# PHP form to database and email

Tags: php, html, database, forms, email

I have a question regarding a form I made.

It's a big form and what I want is that I receive all the input in my database (I have accomplished this so far) and that I get an email including all the results from my form. Eventually what I want is a neat stylized email that provides the complete question and the answer filled in by the client.

In short: I want all the questions and answers from my form put together in an email.

```
<div class="formulier">
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="action.php"> 
    <div id="alginfo">
      <div class="col-md-12 red">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="numbers">1</h3>
          <h3 class="title">Algemene informatie</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="tekstenveld">
            <input type="text" class="bigv bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" required>
            <p>Bedrijfsnaam</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tekstenveld">
            <input type="text" class="bigv volledigenaam" name="volledigenaam" required>
            <p>Volledige naam</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="tekstenveld">
            <input type="text" class="bigv telefoonnummer" name="telefoonnummer" required>
            <p>Telefoonnummer</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tekstenveld">
            <input type="text" class="bigv email" name="email" required>
            <p>E-mail</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="multikeuze">
            <h4>Betreft het een:</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="error"></span>
              <input class="multikeuzes" type="checkbox" name="website" id="website" value="website">
              <label for="website" name="website">Website</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="webshop" id="webshop" value="webshop">
              <label for="website" name="webshop">Webshop</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="app" id="app" value="app">
              <label for="website" name="app">App</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="onlinemarketing" id="onlinemarketing" value="onlinemarketing">
              <label for="website" name="onlinemarketing">Online marketing</label></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Anders</p>
            <input type="text" class="bigv anders" name="alginfoanders">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center" id="finish">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

So that's my html, it's only a small part of the form because including everything would make it unnecessarily big.
Now here comes my action.php it is also shortened so I hope you can still understand what's going on.

```
<?php
$servername = "youdliketoknowthat.com";
$username = "butitssecret";
$password = "hunter123";
$dbname = "yougettheidea";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = 'me@myemail.com';

$subject = 'Content formulier';

$headers = "From: me@myemail.com\r\n";

$message = 'Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijfsnaam;
$message .= 'Volledige naam: ' . $volledigenaam;
$message .= 'Telefoonnummer: ' . $telefoonnummer;
$message .= 'email: ' . $email;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
$volledigenaam = $_POST['volledigenaam'];
$telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if($volledigenaam !=''||$email !='');
$website = $_POST['website'];
$webshop = $_POST['webshop'];
$app = $_POST['app'];
$onlinemarketing = $_POST['onlinemarketing'];

{

$sql = "INSERT INTO intake_formulier_test (bedrijfsnaam, volledigenaam, telefoonnummer, email, website, webshop, app, onlinemarketing)
VALUES ('$bedrijfsnaam', '$volledigenaam', '$telefoonnummer', '$email', '$website', '$webshop', '$app', '$onlinemarketing')";
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I hope I made it clear what I am trying to accomplish. 
I feel like this should be so easy yet I can't find an answer on Google that applies to what I am trying to do.

Comment: So what ? Is there a problem or something ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Toto This question is about a specific programming issue (my code is supposed to send me a summary by email, it doesn't). How on earth is that not suitable here? Even though it wasn't, this question is [off-topic for codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as it contains broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

Dont put this :

```
$message = 'Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijfsnaam;
```

Before this:

```
$bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
```

Same things for all others variables used for your mail() function

Your php script should be like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "youdliketoknowthat.com";
$username = "butitssecret";
$password = "hunter123";
$dbname = "yougettheidea";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$bedrijfsnaam = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
$volledigenaam = $_POST['volledigenaam'];
$telefoonnummer = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if($volledigenaam !=''||$email !='');
$website = $_POST['website'];
$webshop = $_POST['webshop'];
$app = $_POST['app'];
$onlinemarketing = $_POST['onlinemarketing'];

{

$sql = "INSERT INTO intake_formulier_test (bedrijfsnaam, volledigenaam, telefoonnummer, email, website, webshop, app, onlinemarketing)
VALUES ('$bedrijfsnaam', '$volledigenaam', '$telefoonnummer', '$email', '$website', '$webshop', '$app', '$onlinemarketing')";
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    // Now we can send email
    $to = 'me@myemail.com';
    $subject = 'Content formulier';
    $headers = "From: me@myemail.com\r\n";
    $message = 'Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijfsnaam;
    $message .= 'Volledige naam: ' . $volledigenaam;
    $message .= 'Telefoonnummer: ' . $telefoonnummer;
    $message .= 'email: ' . $email;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

You were adding things to your $message var like this:
    $message = 'Bedrijfsnaam: ' . $bedrijfsnaam;
But at that point, for this particular exemple, the var $bedrijfsnaam wasn't declared...
So your $message var was empty !
In my example, i put all the things related to emailing infos after DB query, and after all your $var = $_POST["var"]..

Comment: Tip: For a "neat stylized email" you can use html and css in your $message, for that, read Usman Khan answer !  ;)